# Bootstrap carousel indicators prevent event bubbling

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, jquery-events, event-bubbling

Basically, any example here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/ should do the trick.
If you click on the indicators and then repeat the process fast, the animation keeps getting queued on top of itself and you have this weird queue of events chained together.

Is there a way in Javascript to stop the addition of these queues?
Let's say for example, I add a console log as so on the slide callback:

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
  console.log("slide")
})
```

Then if I check my console it will look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE90b.png):

[image]

How do I prevent that number from continually increasing as I press the indicators in Javascript?
How would I do it for a on click event?

Comment: Seems natural to me but you can use your own custom function with something like  ‍‍`event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: @mhrabiee hmm, how would I do that? if I just do this `$('#carouselExampleCaptions').on('slide.bs.carousel',function(e){
e.stopPropagation();console.log("slide")})` it still works like before

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if anyone ever encounter this, this is how I solved it.

I added an extra class is-animated on the body (you can add it anywhere) then removed it with a 0.6 second timeout (the same time as the bootstrap animation duration in css).

```
jQuery('#carouselExampleCaptions').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    if ($("body").hasClass("is-animating")) {
      return false;
    }
    $('body').addClass('is-animating');
    // Do your code here
    setTimeout(function () {$('body').removeClass('is-animating')}, 600);
});
```